# How to create multiple dropdowns that call different stored procedures with it's previous dropdown selection as an argument?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, ado

I have 4 dropdowns. Each dropdown "depends" on the one above it. For example, when a user selects from Dropdown A, Dropdown B needs to call a stored procedure and filter its select options based on what was selected on Dropdown A. Same idea for the rest of the dropdowns. Dropdown C would get filtered based on Dropdown B....

What is the best way to go about this? Examples or any any helpful links would be great! :)
This is for a website that makes use of ASP Classic, HTML, and JavaScript

Thank you!

Comment: Don't know a thing about ASP Classic, but if it was on ASP.Net you could put those DropDownLists into an UpdatePanel, set their AutoPostBack to true, initially disable all of them but the first one, set their OnSelectedIndexChanged to DataBind and enable the next one and so on. No Javascript needed then.

Answer (score 0):

After I posted my comment, I left the laziness behind and found this: http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?181927-Allowing-Autopostback-after-dropdown-selection...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With or without apparent postback?

**With postback**, you have several avenues. You could have each drop-down to post to a different page, or you can have them all post to the same page, and have logic to determine which drop-down posted.

Here's a concept of the the earlier approach:

```
<script>
    function SubmitTo(where) {
        alert(where);
        f1.action = where + ".asp";
        f1.submit();
    }
</script>
<form name="f1" method="post">
<select name="a" id="a" onchange="SubmitTo('page1')"><option></option><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
<br />
<select name="b" id="b" onchange="SubmitTo('page2')"><option></option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select>
<br />
<select name="c" id="c" onchange="SubmitTo('page3')"><option></option><option>5</option><option>6</option></select>
<br />
<select name="d" id="d" onchange="SubmitTo('page4')"><option></option><option>7</option><option>8</option></select>
</form>
```

**Without post back**, using AJAX, you do something similar, except that you move the bulding of the result into your browser. Basically you create individual "onChange client-script handlers (or listeners) that do two things: 1. AJAX-call web-server page to retrive the data for the "next" drop down, and 2. When the result comes, "build" the next drop-down.